# VbA Access compile: Method or data member not found

Tags: vba

I have this code in VBA:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'when we click on button Add there are two options
    '1. for insert
    '2. for update
    If Me.Barcode & "" = "" Then
        'this is for insert new
        'add data to table
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tab_barcodeki([date], [time], category, barcode) " & _
                " VALUES(" & Me.Date & ",'" & Me.Time & "','" & _
                Me.Category & "','" & Me.Barcode & "')"
    Else
        'otherwise (Tag of barcode store the id of liquid to be modified)
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tab_barcodeki " & _
                " SET [date]=" & Me.Date & _
                ", [time]='" & Me.Time & "'" & _
                ", category='" & Me.Category & "'" & _
                ", barcode='" & Me.Barcode & "'" & _
                " WHERE barcode=" & Me.Barcode.Tag

    End If

    'clear form
    cmdClear_Click
    'refresh data in list on form
    tab_barcodekisubform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

When I compile I have compile error, method or data member not found. I checked already the name of table column and textbox, textbox links are same.
Do you have any idea the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace references like `Me.Date` with `Me!Date`.

This applies to `Me.Date`, `Me.Time`, `Me.Barcode`, `Me.Category`.

Replace `Me.Barcode.Tag` with `Me!Barcode.Tag`.

You can use `.` to refer only to true properties. So `Me.Date` expectects that the forms has `Date` property – and it doesn't have, so you get the error. When referring to names of form members, use `!` instead of dot.

Comment: I did your mention, but now I have another compile error: "Invalid or unqualified reference" when I want Edit function like Me!Date = .Fields("date")

Comment: @RóbertVizi – do you have field named `date`?  Maybe you can try to rename it to `date1` or `CreationDate` because AFAIK, `date`is reserved word.

Comment: Yes the field named date, but I dont want to rename it, because it depends on many query. But the insert, delete, update functions worked fine, just I get compile error message. So thank you

Comment: @RóbertVizi – Try `Me![date]`